# How to get a power to work as an argument to work as a function

Tags: r, function

I have a function and would like to have the order of regression interactions as an argument. However, I can only do this manually. Is there a way I can put in a variable name and assign that variable to a number depending on the power? Ideally I would like the argument to read `Order=m` and have a single line of code where `m` is the power My code is the following:

```
Ord_eval <- function(MyData, distance_compound, seed = NA, cov, vals = NA, Order = 1){

  regressors <- ~ lograte  + Monocot + Warm + Method -1
  
  if (Order==2){
    regressors <- ~ lograte  + Monocot + Warm + Method)^2-1
  }
  else if (Order==3){
    regressors <- ~ lograte  + Monocot + Warm + Method)^3-1
  }
  else if (Order==4){
    regressors <- ~ lograte  + Monocot + Warm + Method)^4-1
  }
}  

Thank you.
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to **open** the parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend `bquote`:

```
Ord_eval <- function(MyData, distance_compound, seed = NA, cov, vals = NA, Order = 1){
  
  eval(bquote(~ (lograte  + Monocot + Warm + Method) ^ .(Order) -1))

}  

Ord_eval(Order = 3)
#~(lograte + Monocot + Warm + Method)^3 - 1
#<environment: 0x000001e30f019010>
```

PS: Usually, it is a bad idea to fit a model without intercept.